# View PowerBI without Desktop app, internet access, or on-premise report server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Is there a way to view a PowerBI report without the PowerBI Desktop app, without internet access (publishing online is not possible), and without on-premise report server?

I would like to display reports on computers and screens throughout our company, but do not have internet access on them (not possible, fully restricted). Seems we also cannot install on-premise service. Is there a way to view a .pbix without the desktop app itself?

Or am I looking for an option that just does not exist?

Thanks!

Comment: The only alternative I thought about was viewing in SharePoint but this looks like its only for SharePoint Online - [View Power BI files in OneDrive and SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-sharepoint-viewer). Report server would be your only option, otherwise you'll need to consider using Excel (which has the almost the same data model capabilities).